# How do I get the list of specs, their descriptions and results in my own object?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jsfiddle

I'm trying to build a custom jasmine reporter that runs on jsfiddle. All I need, is the data inside the `jasmine` object so that I can print it on the DOM the way I want.

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divyanthj/n85auoan/8/)

Answer (score 0):

I used `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.suite.specs_` to get what I need. Worked like a charm.